# How do I run a visual studio project from another computer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, socket.io

That's probably I really dumb question but I really need an answear.
I made this javascript project for school and I used socket.io and node.js. Right now, in order to get it to run, I write in the terminal the "node ." cmd. I have to copy the project to a flash drive, bring it to school and then present it in front of the class, but I'm wondering, will the "node ." command work once I open the project from another computer?

Comment: It should work provided node is installed on that computer..  I don't think VS Code is required to run the project, it's just an IDE that makes development easier.

Comment: In school, we are working in visual studio code, and this project was like a homework for us. So now when I get back to the school pc do I need to install node in order for it to work?

Comment: @MikeChristensen VSC is not an IDE, it is just a plain editor with a few extensions/plugins

Comment: @rioV8 Does it provide an environment to develop in?  Does it integrate with things?  Then it's an IDE.

Comment: @MikeChristensen VSC does not maintain some build file (Project Solution) for you so VSC is an editor with benefits. Just as Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you going to open the cmd in the folder of your project, and there's a terminal in the main vscode. So don't worry

Comment: This can probably be a comment instead of an answer

Comment: I can't add comment in the main post, should need 50 reputation points. Sorry

Comment: okay let me help you get some reputation points, starting with upvoting your answer, all the best !